# TextView não fica alinhado abaixo com a propriedade android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho dois texts views que vão aparecer em um ListView e quero que um fica alinhado acima e outro abaixo, mas não está funcionando do jeito que estou fazendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_lista_notify"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto_notificacao_list"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto_hora_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tenta trocar de LinearLayour para RelativeLayout

Comment: Mas eu estou usando LINEAR layout na outra listview e a propriedade gravity está funcionando, não é isso não , mas vlw

Comment: Então tenta ```android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"```

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264476/2541).