# Posicionar botão na parte inferior do layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de posicionar o botão Sair no final do meu layout. Estou usando LinearLayout. Alguma dica de como posso posicionar ?

Este é o código do Linear Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.meuprojeto.perfilloginsenha.PerfilActivity">
```

Este é o código do botão:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogOut"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="SAIR"
    android:textColor="@color/branco"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

[image: layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao contrário do que se possa pensar, num LinearLayout, `match_parent` não faz com que ele ocupe todo o *parent*. O nome antigo, `fill_parent`, nesse sentido, ainda era pior.

Coloque uma view antes do botão de forma que ela ocupe todo o espaço que resta do layout. Isso obrigará a que o botão seja posicionado na parte inferior.

Para que uma *view* ocupe todo o espaço restante disponível deve a ela ser atribuído um `layout_weight`.

Exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Botão"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Uma alternativa é usar um RelativeLayout e adicionar `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` ao botão:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Botão"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: atribui o `<Space...>`  com a propriedade `android:layout_weight="1"` e nada aconteceu, porém quando alterei o `layout_height` de zero para outro valor ele desceu, porém acho que não seria o ideal, pois seria uma gambiarra e em telas menores o botão esconderia.

Comment: O *layout* da resposta foi testado, por isso funciona. Como você não colocou o seu *layout* completo não sei se haverá algo mais que necessite de ser feito.

Comment: fiz um teste com seu código realmente funciona, vou verificar no meu o que pode estar diferente