# Posicionar Button no centro de um LinearLayout com layout_gravity

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de saber porque não consigo centralizar o botão, gostaria de centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente, mas ao que parece-me center só centraliza horizontalmente no layout vertical e vice-versa.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sayhello.ActivityPrincipal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="ok"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Está usando LinearLayout? Coloque o layout todo pra termos certeza de qual é o problema.

Comment: Relacionado: [Posicionar botão na parte inferior do layout](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264476/2541).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao contrário do que se possa pensar, num LinearLayout, `match_parent` não faz com que ele ocupe todo o *parent*. O nome antigo, `fill_parent`, nesse sentido, ainda era pior.

Assim sendo e querendo usar o atributo `android:layout_gravity` terá de incluir o Button entre duas views "auxiliares" com um `layout_weight` para indicar que elas deve ocupar todo o espaço disponível acima e abaixo do Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="ok"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

No entanto esse efeito é mais fácil de conseguir usando um RelativeLayout com `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="ok" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para deixar o botão centralizado na tela, você pode colocar uma gravidade no pai:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center"
  tools:context="com.example.android.sayhello.ActivityPrincipal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="ok"/>
```

Comment: Boa! Na altura em que respondi não me lembrei dessa alternativa.

Answer (score -1):

Pode faze-lo usando RelativeLayout. Mas se quiser mesmo fazer com LinearLayout pode usar o android:layout_marginTop para centralizar, mas esta abordagem pode dar problema no futuro.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
        android:text="ok" />
</RelativeLayout>
```